# In Git, how to squash all commits related to a file or folder?

Tags: git

How to squash all commits related to a specific file or folder? I can probably collect the hashes in a first step, and then pipe them as input to a second command.

It would also be acceptable to modify commits in order to remove the parts related to specific files or folders, with all recent changes there being committed by a new, single commit.

To make the use case clearer, let us say that i want to eliminate the history related to specific files

Comment: All commits throughout your entire history or fairly close to your current `HEAD`?

Comment: All commits throughout the entire history, related to a specific file or folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use git filter-branch, like this :

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf FOLDERNAME' HEAD
```

More info here : http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Be really careful with this command, this it's rewriting the entire history. Be sure to have a backup copy of your repository somewhere.

Comment: So i could copy the folder somewhere else, use filter branch with `rm` and than copy the folder back and commit it. Brilliant!

Comment: The doc says that `.gitignore` is not taken into account when using `--tree-filter`, so i removed directories which i wanted to ignore, before running the command. It worked fine!